# NSDate for each day of month

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I've browsed through the stackoverflow, but none of the solutions didn't work well.
I want to generate NSDate array of days in month, this is the code I am using (year and month hardcoded for now):

```
NSCalendar *c = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSRange days = [c rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay
                       inUnit:NSCalendarUnitMonth
                      forDate:today];

for (int i = 1; i <= days.length; i++) {
    NSDateComponents *dc = [NSDateComponents new];
    [dc setYear:2015];
    [dc setMonth:12];
    [dc setDay:i];
    NSDate *d = [calendar dateFromComponents:dc];
    [arrayDates addObject:d];
}
```

The problem is that the first objects would always be(previous month last day) :

```
2015-11-30 23:00:00 +0000
```

and the last would be (not the last day of current month)
 `2015-12-30 23:00:00 +0000`

I've tried setting different locale, calendar options, but nothing helps..
any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels like a timezone/locale problem. I wonder if it goes away if you set an explicit locale and also an explicit hour in the middle of the day:

```
[calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
```

Then, when you're creating the dates, something like this:

```
[dc setHour:12];
```

The reason I think it's a timezone/locale issue is because I tried your code here and it worked exactly right first time.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the answer, but this will work when you set the month:12 but try settings month:11, you will get 31 days, which is wrong, should be 30 days.

Comment: I expect that's because `days` is being calculated using a variable called `today`, which I imagine is literally today – i.e., a day in December.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I need a break definetely. Thank you!

Comment: You're most welcome! This will teach you for working late on a Sunday evening ;)

Comment: The night is still young my friend! :) Thank you once again!